# Have any countries abolished or significantly curtailed the requirement to conduct Environmental impact assessments?

Tags: environmental-policy

As [per Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_impact_assessment):

> Environmental Impact assessment (EIA) is the assessment of the environmental consequences of a plan, policy, program, or actual projects prior to the decision to move forward with the proposed action.

They're mandatory in the EU, US, Canada and many other nations worldwide. Are there examples of nations (or subnational entities) which previously mandated EIAs to be conducted but since entirely abolished the requirement or significantly curtailed it?

Comment: In the U.S. this arises under the National Environmental Policy Act, but I would assume that most countries never had one in the first place. Also, do ad hoc exceptions for particular projects or policies count?

Comment: @ohwilleke only if there’s such a large number of exceptions that most projects end up not doing environmental assessments at all.

Answer (score 2):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany) has decided to [build LNG terminals](https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/suche/erster-lng-terminal-2143122) with an accelerated procedure when Russia broke their delivery contracts.

Comment: It seems common to have accelerated procedures for major, urgent infrastructure projects. [UK governments](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/fast-track-planning-route-to-speed-up-major-infrastructure-projects) have proposed something similar although I'm not sure of the specifics or how much it has been used.

Comment: Same in Poland. Our gov loves to arrange, long onerous environmental procedures, however regularly exempts (fully or partially) its flagship projects from them.